# How to validate in UpdateView without validating through a form?

Tags: python, django

My company is currently using a custom task management library (viewflow) and I am given an [UpdateProcessView](https://github.com/viewflow/viewflow/blob/385fceb3b486c52d7a7375ca2e738874497cd0c4/viewflow/flow/views/task.py#L93). The view updates the process that governs all the tasks and I would like to override this to verify call `form_valid` only if certain conditions are met.

Since I do not have control over the form that gets submitted to this view, writing a custom form to validate is out of the question (we tried this before and it got very messy).

Given this circumstances, where is the next best place to insert my validation logic? I am checking if certain fields in [self.model](https://github.com/viewflow/viewflow/blob/385fceb3b486c52d7a7375ca2e738874497cd0c4/viewflow/flow/views/task.py#L100) are present.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can look into Model's [clean](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) method. You can try like this:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class YourModel(models.Model):
    ...
    def clean(self):
       if self.something is 'wrong':
           raise ValidationError("Something is wrong")

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.full_clean()
        return super(YourModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

If i did understand well your question and your issue, i think you're trying to do something like this example:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.urls impot reverse_lazy
# If you want to use the django's messages framework
from django.contrib import messages

class MyCustomView(UpdateProcessView):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Initialize the parents of MycustomView class
        super().__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    # Then override form_valid method
    def form_valid(self, form):
        # You need to verify is self.model is iterable or not
        # If not, you need to find a way to pass your conditions 
        # with self.model elements
        if 'elm1' in self.model:
            messages.error(self.request, "Condition 1 is not met")
            return redirect(reverse_lazy('my_url1_name'))
        elif 'elm2' in self.model:
            messages.error(self.request, "Condition 2 is not met")
            return redirect(reverse_lazy('my_url2_name'))

        messages.success(self.request, "Valid request")
        # which will return a HttpResponseRedirect
        return super().form_valid()
```